# Data Security and Location

Tags: location

Does CiviCRM have servers located in Canada and can they assure Canadian clients that their data is stored only on those servers?

Comment: By and large, civicrm is something that you decide where to host, unless you are using Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the ["spark"](https://civicrm.org/spark) product offered separately by CiviCRM?

You don't have to use spark you can download and install CiviCRM yourself with any hosting company. If you are looking for someone to set it up for you then take a look at https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: Indeed, most people utilize their own hosting for running CiviCRM. As such, you can locate a host that has servers in Canada and that your information is only stored there.

Answer (score 0):

My partner Alan Dixon and I host/store all our client CiviCRM instances/data on a number of private dedicated servers in Toronto and Montreal data centres and also work exclusively with partners/consults in Canada (i.e. we do not outsource to sub-contractors outside of Canada).